# RIA Services query: Nested "from" and include children

Tags: linq, wcf-ria-services

I have the following [schema](http://i41.tinypic.com/548xuq.jpg).

What I'd like to do is to retrieve all customers (and children properties) from a selected StaffAssignment by StaffId.

So I've written the following query:

```
from c in ObjectContext.Customers.Include("Assignments.Activities")
               from a in c.Assignments
               from sa in a.StaffAssignments
               where sa.StaffId == staffId
               select c
```

But children properties aren't loaded (I added the [Include] in service metadata file as well).

What did I do wrong?

Gtz,
Stéphane.

Comment: Wish I could find a single instance of this same question that someone has an answer to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624348/ria-services-not-returning-included-type-collection-property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603145/ria-services-entity-with-collection-is-empty-when-not-supposed-to

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

This is my **model** (taken from NorthWind)

[image]

And the **DomainService** looks like:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class DomainService1 : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<AdventureWorksLT2008Entities>
{
    public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomer()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Customer.Include("CustomerAddress").Include("CustomerAddress.Address");
    }
}
```

I've added [Include] attributes on all navigation properties:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    internal sealed class CustomerMetadata
    {
        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private CustomerMetadata() { }

        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Include]
        public EntityCollection<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddress { get; set; }
```

And in the client code, I use this:

```
var dc = new MyDomainContext();

var query = dc.GetCustomerQuery();

var op = dc.Load(query, loadOperation =>
{
    var customer = loadOperation.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
    var address = customer.CustomerAddress.FirstOrDefault().Address;
}, null);
```

Note that this does only work when:

- ObjectContext is auto generated by EntityFramework (no custom Context or Poco entities)
- The DomainService is a 'LinqToEntitiesDomainService'

See also [this link](https://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/using-wcf-ria-services-to-include-multi-table-master-detail-data/).