# Ria Services Entity with collection is empty when not supposed to?

Tags: wcf-ria-services

Hi I'm have an object model with an Employee and EmployeeWorksiteReference (cause it's an many to many relation I have and middle entity).

I use Association, Include and Composition tags on it to be able to send it over as one when saving and so on, and when saveing it works perfectly. But when I load an Employee with some EmployeeWorksiteReferences the collection turns up empty on the client, when I check in the debugger exactly before it returns the result the list contains instances but on the client when it receives the result the list is just empty.

What can I have made wrong?

Comment: This is the exact same issue I'm having. I still haven't found the cause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624348/ria-services-not-returning-included-type-collection-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many long hours of debugging a similar issue I found that the problem, in my case, was due to not explicitly including the intermediary table entity in my model.  I finally fixed the issue by adding the missing intermediary type and updating the metadata to reflect it.

See my full solution to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624348/ria-services-not-returning-included-type-collection-property).